# Focusing forms after button click

Tags: c#, winforms

If I click a button event in form1, form2 should be focus and if I click button event in form2, form1 should focus in c#.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

Store a reference to the other form (ie Form1 has a reference to Form2) and in the button click event handlers, use:

```
otherFormInstance.Focus();
```

Answer (score 1):

Microsoft recommends not calling Focus on a form, instead use the form's Activate method.  Here is an excerpt from MSDN:

> Focus is a low-level method intended
>   primarily for custom control authors.
>   Instead, application programmers
>   should use the Select method or the
>   ActiveControl property for child
>   controls, or the Activate method for
>   forms.